# appium just flashes white Screen and does not open the app

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am facing a strange issue, appium just flashes white Screen and does not open the app and if i keep the app open manually in the emulator it works. This issue just happen all of sudden.

My Observations on this issue. ( Not aware how to resolve this )

- it happens only for few apps like Telegram
- in the appium logs i dont see appPackage and Activity ( even though i have set capabilities)
- in the logs i see this msg "[UiAutomator2] Neither 'app' nor 'appPackage' was set. Starting UiAutomator2 without the target application
  "
- in the logs i see  " [AndroidDriver] No app sent in, not parsing package/activity "

Solutions I tried:

1. updated the app
2. appPackage and Activity is correct
3. tried clearing the cache of the app / reinstalled it
4. tried in real device still no luck

Any help is much appreciated

Logs are too lengthy to attach here

Answer (score 0):

its resolved, It was a silly mistake, i had given a different property and in the desired caps i used a different property name (basically the place where i am storing the appPackage and Activity name and where i am using it was different )